# Binary addition Checksum in Java

Tags: java, checksum

I'm trying to implement a checksum for a message. The specification is that:

> The checksum is implemented such that
>   the entire message wrapper and the
>   message data, excluding the checksum,
>   is a result of a simple binary
>   addition truncated to four bytes.

I'm afraid I have no idea how to do it in Java, though. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

M.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what uses that kind of checksum? Unless I misunderstand it, it's a *very* bad checksum. It doesn't detect any error where two bytes are swapped, for example.

Comment: That is part of the STANAG 4586 specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They probably mean a simple unsigned addition of all the bytes (assuming a 8-bit byte is the smallest unit in whatever you interact with):

```
byte[] data = getTheDataFromSomewhere();
long checksum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  checksum += (data[i] & 0xFF);
}
checksum = checksum & 0xFFFFFFFFL; // truncate to 4 byte
```

You could use an `int` there as well, but that would result in a negative number. Bit-wise it would be equivalent, but this way it's easier to compare values.

Comment: Thank you very much Joachim, I'll give this a go. The size of the checksum, according to specification, is 4 bytes, so it sounds like I'll be using an int. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: The reason I've been using a `long` is that an `int` is signed (so is a long, but if only the first 4 byte are used, then it's always positive) and most of those protocols assume unsigned operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use the java standard library function. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Comment: Thanks jogabonito, I'm just reading this - just to check, should this do the binary addition detailed above?

Comment: Nope, that does [CRC32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), which is a very simple and standardized checksum algorithm but still a bit more complicated than binary addition.